# How to solve error: class x Binding is public, should be declared in a file named x .java public final class x Binding implements ViewBinding {

Tags: java, android-databinding

When i Try to build then this error will come. Actually i have integrated another app source code in my existing app source code. Error: class ActivitySigUupBinding is public, should be declared in a file named ActivitySignUpBinding.java public final class ActivitySigUupBinding implements ViewBinding

ActivitySignUpBinding.java ⬇️

```
public final class ActivitySignUpBinding implements ViewBinding {
@NonNull
private final ConstraintLayout rootView;

@NonNull
public final EditText editText;

@NonNull
public final ImageView imageView;

@NonNull
public final EditText password;

@NonNull
public final ProgressBar pb;

@NonNull
public final TextView privacy;

@NonNull
public final Button signUp;

@NonNull
public final TextView terms;

@NonNull
public final TextView textView;

@NonNull
public final TextView textView2;

@NonNull
public final EditText username;

private ActivitySignUpBinding(@NonNull ConstraintLayout rootView, @NonNull EditText
editText,
  @NonNull ImageView imageView, @NonNull EditText password, @NonNull ProgressBar pb,
  @NonNull TextView privacy, @NonNull Button signUp, @NonNull TextView terms,
  @NonNull TextView textView, @NonNull TextView textView2, @NonNull EditText username) {
this.rootView = rootView;
this.editText = editText;
this.imageView = imageView;
this.password = password;
this.pb = pb;
this.privacy = privacy;
this.signUp = signUp;
this.terms = terms;
this.textView = textView;
this.textView2 = textView2;
this.username = username;
}

@Override
@NonNull
public ConstraintLayout getRoot() {
return rootView;
}

@NonNull
public static ActivitySignUpBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
return inflate(inflater, null, false);
}

@NonNull
public static ActivitySignUpBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
  @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sign_up, parent, false);
if (attachToParent) {
  parent.addView(root);
}
return bind(root);
}

@NonNull
public static ActivitySignUpBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
// The body of this method is generated in a way you would not otherwise write.
// This is done to optimize the compiled bytecode for size and performance.
int id;
missingId: {
  id = R.id.editText;
  EditText editText = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (editText == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.imageView;
  ImageView imageView = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (imageView == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.password;
  EditText password = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (password == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.pb;
  ProgressBar pb = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (pb == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.privacy;
  TextView privacy = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (privacy == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.signUp;
  Button signUp = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (signUp == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.terms;
  TextView terms = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (terms == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.textView;
  TextView textView = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (textView == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.textView2;
  TextView textView2 = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (textView2 == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  id = R.id.username;
  EditText username = rootView.findViewById(id);
  if (username == null) {
    break missingId;
  }

  return new ActivitySignUpBinding((ConstraintLayout) rootView, editText, imageView,
  password,
      pb, privacy, signUp, terms, textView, textView2, username);
  }
  String missingId = rootView.getResources().getResourceName(id);
  throw new NullPointerException("Missing required view with ID: ".concat(missingId));
}
}
```

FrontSignup.java ⬇️

```
public class FrontSignup extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivitySignupBinding binding;
Activity activity;
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
AlertDialog loadingDialog,alert;
Session session;
boolean check=false;
boolean email_=false;
boolean emailactive= false;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 0;
private Bitmap bitmap;
String filepath,encodedimage;
int type;
Uri image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
    binding=ActivitySignupBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    activity=FrontSignup.this;
    session= new Session(activity);
    loadingDialog=Method.loading(activity);
    alert=Method.Alerts(activity);

    if(Constant.EMAIL_VERIFICATION){
        type=2;
    }else {
        type=5;
    }

    binding.layoutImg.setOnClickListener(v -> Dexter.withActivity(FrontSignup
            .this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {}
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check());

    binding.sendAgain.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        funVerifyEmail(binding.email.getText().toString().trim());
    });

    binding.terms.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Method.launchCustomTabs(activity, Constant.PRIVACY_POLICY_URL);
    });
}

void showLoading(){
    loadingDialog.show();
}

void dismisLoading(){
    if(loadingDialog.isShowing())
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
}

private boolean validateData() {
    boolean valid= true;

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.username.getText().toString().trim())){
        binding.username.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        valid=false;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.email.getText().toString().trim())){
        binding.email.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        valid=false;
    }
    else if(!binding.email.getText().toString().trim().matches(emailPattern)){
        binding.email.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        valid=false;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.password.getText().toString().trim())){
        binding.password.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        valid=false;
    }

    if(image==null){
        showAlert(getString(R.string.please_select_profile_image));
        valid=false;
    }
    return valid;
}

public void Signup(View view) {
    if(!Method.isConnected(activity)){
        Method.ToastWarning(activity,getString(R.string.no_internet));
    }
    if(!validateData()){
        return;
    }else {
        if(check){
            if(email_){
                funOtpVerify(binding.email.getText().toString().trim(),binding.otp.getText().toString().trim());
            }else{
                reqSignup(binding.username.getText().toString().trim(),binding.email.getText().toString().trim(),binding.password.getText().toString().trim(),5);
            }
        }else {
            reqSignup(binding.username.getText().toString().trim(),binding.email.getText().toString().trim(),binding.password.getText().toString().trim(),type);
        }
    }
}

private void reqSignup(String name, String email, String password, int types) {
    File file = new File(filepath);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part parts = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("newimage", file.getName(), requestBody);
    OSDeviceState device = OneSignal.getDeviceState();
    Constant.API_TYPE = "signup";
    Constant.P1 = name;
    Constant.P2 = email;
    Constant.P3 = password;
    Constant.P4 = Method.deviceId(activity);
    Constant.P5 = device.getUserId();
    Constant.P6 = String.valueOf(types);
    showLoading();
    Call<BonusResponse> call = ApiClient.getClient(activity).create(ApiInterface.class).Signup(parts);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BonusResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BonusResponse> call, Response<BonusResponse> response) {
           dismisLoading();
            if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getStatus()==201){
                check=true;
                if(types==5){
                    session.saveUserData("",email,"","",password,"","","","");
                    session.setBoolean(session.LOGIN,true);
                    Method.ToastSuccess(activity,"Account Created!");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FrontLogin.class);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    binding.loginLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    binding.layoutOtp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    funVerifyEmail(email);
                }
            }else{
                Method.ToastError(activity,response.body().getData());
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BonusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            dismisLoading();
        }
    });
}

public void login(View view) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.exit,R.anim.enter);
    startActivity(new Intent(activity,FrontLogin.class));
}

private void funOtpVerify(String email , String otp) {
    if(otp.isEmpty()){
        Method.ToastWarning(activity,"Enter Valid Otp");
    }else {
        showLoading();
        Call<BonusResponse> call = ApiClient.getClient(activity).create(ApiInterface.class).Verify_OTP(otp, email);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<BonusResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BonusResponse> call, Response<BonusResponse> response) {
                dismisLoading();
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getStatus() == 201) {
                    reqSignup(binding.username.getText().toString().trim(), binding.email.getText().toString().trim(), binding.password.getText().toString().trim(), 5);
                } else {
                    binding.otp.setText(null);
                    Method.ToastError(activity, response.body().getData());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BonusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                dismisLoading();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void funVerifyEmail(String email) {
    emailactive=true;
    showLoading();
    Call<BonusResponse> call = ApiClient.getClient(activity).create(ApiInterface.class).VerifyEmail(email);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BonusResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BonusResponse> call, Response<BonusResponse> response) {
            dismisLoading();
            if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getStatus()==201) {
                email_=true;
                Method.ToastSuccess(activity,"OTP has been sended To Email");
                binding.procced.setText(getString(R.string.verify_otp));
            } else {
                Method.ToastWarning(activity,response.body().getData());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BonusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            dismisLoading();
            Method.ToastWarning(activity,getString(R.string.try_again_later));
        }
    });
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        image = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(image);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false);

            binding.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            filepath=getRealPathFromURI(image);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

void showAlert(String msg){
    alert.show();
    TextView tv =alert.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tv.setText(msg);
    alert.findViewById(R.id.close).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        alert.dismiss();
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(emailactive){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.txt_exit));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.txt_confirm_exit));

        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.txt_yes), (dialog, which) -> {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.exit,R.anim.enter);
            finish();
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.txt_no), (dialog, which) -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Error ⬇️
[image: Error Coming while building App]